# How do I get the current keyboard layout in Ubuntu in a format such as 'us'?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm using i3 window manager, Ubuntu 20.04.
I ran the following commands to set up two keyboard layouts:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,tr
setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
```

This allows me to toggle between the two keyboard layouts `us` and `tr` with alt-shift.
I want to get a short output, `us` or `tr`, from the command line that tells me which keyboard layout I'm currently on.

The following command gives me `us` as the output, even when I've switched to `tr`.
`setxkbmap -print | awk -F"+" '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}'`

The full output of `setxkbmap -print` is below:

```
xkb_keymap {                                                                                           
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };                                             
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };                                                     
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };                                                     
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+tr:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+capslock(escape)"};    
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };                                                     
};
```

**How can I get the current keyboard layout in the command line?**

Comment: Try `setxkbmap -query | grep variant`. Otherwise [xkblayout-state](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state) might work with the command `xkblayout-state print "%s"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use
[xkblayout-state](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state):

> xkblayout-state is a small command-line program to get/set the current XKB keyboard layout.

The command to use is:

```
xkblayout-state print "%s"
```

Comment: thank you. The steps to install xkblayout-state are: `git clone https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state.git` `cd xkblayout-state` `make` `./xkblayout-state print "%s" `

Comment: On some distributions it may be found in the repository.